# Load jquery serialized data into a form

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, populate

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to populate a form if you have that form serialized already? For example, if I have `var form = $('#myform').serialize()`, how should I load that data into a form? Is there a jquery function available or should I just manually set all the values in the form?

Example form:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="first_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"/>
    <select name="gender">
        <option val=""></option>
        <option val="male">Male</option>
        <option val="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

So I'm looking for a fast & easy way to repopulate the same blank form with the serialized data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @Johan's answer is quite good, the best solution for me so far was formParams. I converted my form into a json object with `$('#myform').serializeArray()`, then post it to a script via ajax, save it in the database. When I had to repopulate the form I simply used an ajax request to fetch the json stored form data and used it with `$('#myForm').formParams()`.

I wonder why jquery didn't implement such a function into the framework...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [snippet](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/) below, but change it to use id/class instead of the name property for each element.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
       o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
    });
   return o;
};
```

When you have your form data in key value pairs, you can simply iterate through the object array and map the values. Some psuedo code:

```
$.each(arr, function(k, v){
    $('#newform .' + key).val(v);
});
```